# disable checkbox after modal call

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, bootstrap-modal

Have a checkbox that when checked opens a modal. Once the modal is open I need to disable the checkbox.

```
<input id="cboxText" name="cboxText" value="Y" class="styled" type="checkbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uptext" >
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: Can you paste your  modal code?

Comment: Add a FIDDLE for your problem.

Comment: Add the following line to your modal click event
$('#yourcheckbox').show();

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with jQuery

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#cboxText").click(function() {        
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="cboxText" name="cboxText" value="Y" class="styled" type="checkbox">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x36fcq1/1/)

**Alternate** you can do with Bootstrap [show.bs.modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#uptext').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#cboxText").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="cboxText" name="cboxText" value="Y" class="styled" type="checkbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uptext" >
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3x36fcq1/2/)

Keep in mind, if you have more then one checkbox, you can't use `id="cboxText"`, `ids` must be unique.